# How to search and replace value in array of object literals

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to figure out how to simply search and replace a value (in this case replacing any value equal to null with undefined) in an array of objects like this - the array keys could vary:

```
var array = [{ 
  "name": "mike",
  "age": null
},
{ "name": "jim",
  "age": 99
}];
```

Expected result:

```
var array = [{ 
    "name": mike,
    "age": undefined
  },
  { "name": jim,
    "age": 99
  }];
```

My impression is that I should be able to do this using the map() function but none of the documentation examples are quite making sense to me for this. I have been trying to apply the solution from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915891/2930969 but without any success.

Anyways, if anyone cares to help point me in the right direction here is a framed out codepen you can tinker with: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBxwdj?editors=0012

Comment: what is your expected result..?

Comment: Would help to have valid json, `mike` and `jim` are undefined.

Comment: @PranavCBalan updated

Comment: @Ultimater fair point, fixed

Comment: falling asleep, will revisit this in the morning. thanks.

Comment: codepen has issues with some JavaScript. Try it in your JavaScript console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [{ 
  "name": "mike",
  "age": null
},
{ "name": "jim",
  "age": 99
}];

array = array.map(function(item) {
  if(item.age === null) {
    // delete item.age;
    item.age = undefined;
  }
  
  return item;
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm thinking. I was able to get the result I was looking for by switching 'item.name === mike' to 'item.age === null' - if you switch that I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 2):

Since you said that the keys may vary, you will need to do two loops to cover arbitrary key names. One over the array, and then one over the keys of each object.

```
var nullToUndef = function (a) {
    return a.map(function (o) {
     Object.keys(o).forEach(function (key) {
       if (o[key] === null) {
         o[key] = undefined;
       }
      });
      return o;
    });
  },
  array = [
    { 
      "name": "mike",
      "age": null
    },
    { "name": "jim",
      "age": 99
    },
    {"foo": null,
    "bar": null
    }
  ];

console.log(nullToUndef(array));
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/h9hpng31/)

`nullToUndef` uses [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array, inside of the mapping function it uses [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get a list of the key names on each object. It then checks each property value to see if it is `null` and changes `null` properties to `undefined` before returning the object for the new array.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`forEch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method to iterate and update

```js
var array = [{
  "name": "mike",
  "age": null
}, {
  "name": "jim",
  "age": 99
}];

array.forEach(function(v) {
  v.age === null && (v.age = undefined)
  //or
  // if(v.age === null) v.age = undefined
})

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it,

updated to only change value where name is 'mike' and age is NULL.

note: it's good check existence of property in object before using it.

```js
var array = [{ 
      "name": "mike",
      "age": null
    },
    { "name": "jim",
      "age": 99
    }];

var arr = [];

arr = array.map(function(x) { 
              if(x.hasOwnProperty("age") && x.hasOwnProperty("name") && x["age"] == null && x["name"] == "mike")
                            x["age"] = undefined;
  return x;
                          });

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Seems to be replacing all "age" with the value undefined, even if it didn't start as null

Comment: from OP question: in this case replacing null with undefined

Comment: Sorry, may have been unclear, didn't want to make all 'age' values undefined, just the ones that had originally been null

Answer (score 0):

Filter down your array using some unique/distinguishing property (name in this case? ids are helpful here) and then update the object directly:

```
var mike = array.filter(function(obj) { return obj.name === 'mike' })[0];
mike.age = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

And the reduce way.

```js
var arr = [{ 
  "name": "mike",
  "age": null
},
{ "name": "jim",
  "age": 99
}],
  fixed = arr.reduce((p,c) => (c.age === null && (c.age = void 0), p.concat(c)),[]);
console.log(fixed);
```

Answer (score 0):

the shortest possible code is as below

```
array.map(a => (a.age = a.age === null ? undefined : a.age))

console.log(array)
```