# How to set all item values of an array to 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find out what's the simplest way to set all the items' values of an array to (in this case) 0 (not null, just "0").
This is my array :

```
var usernameAlphaLog = [localStorage.getItem("user1-log"), localStorage.getItem("user2-log"), localStorage.getItem("user3-log")...]
```

I'm not putting the local storage items in a variable becouse I find that it works better this way (at least for me).

Basically I want to set all of these items' values to 0.
Because I'm pretty new to javascript if it's possible, do it in the simplest way, if not the please, if you have an answer, explain it to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want to fill the array with zeroes or do you want to save the zeroes to local storage?

Comment: So, you just want `usernameAlphaLog = [0, 0, 0]`?  You could just set it like that if that's what you want.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). - Have you tried anything? - Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: I want to save the zeroes to local storage.

Comment: I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915789/how-to-replace-an-item-in-an-array-with-javascript  
but I can't seem to get it working (I made it change a value once but I need to change all values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
int count =13; //the number of user-logs that you have
for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem("user" + i + "-log", 0);
    //usernameAlphaLog.push(localStorage.getItem("user" + i + "-log");
}
```

If you want to store the values in an array, you can do like above or add it with the above:

```
var usernameAlphaLog = [ ];
for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    usernameAlphaLog.push(localStorage.getItem("user" + i + "-log");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
usernameAlphaLog = usernameAlphaLog.map(x => x = 0);
```

Comment: This will not work as expected because `map` don't affect the original array.

Try this: 
`usernameAlphaLog = usernameAlphaLog.map(x => 0);`

Answer (score 1):

`usernameAlphaLog.fill(0)` should replace all values with 0.

Comment: great and simple answer