# How to replace elements in an array given specific indexes of the elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var array = ['odd', 'odd', 2, 8, 'odd', 4];
var oddArr = [1, 3, 5];
```

how to replace 'odd' in array with elements from oddArr, so that

```
var newArr = [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4];
```

?

Comment: What is `odd` defined as?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace an item in an array with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915789/how-to-replace-an-item-in-an-array-with-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

loop through the array and if you find `odd` replace it with the element from `oddArr` using `array.shift()`

```js
const array = ['odd', 'odd', 2, 8, 'odd', 4];
const oddArr = [1, 3, 5];

const result = array.map(e => e === 'odd' ? oddArr.shift() : e)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: While this correctly answers the question, do note that this mutates the `oddArr`. Some may not expect or want this postcondition.

Comment: what if odd are more then the length of the odd array ?

Comment: @G.aziz then the `result` will have `undefined` entries. This is acceptable behavior for such an invalid precondition to calling this.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `map` and an index variable like this:

```js
var array = ["odd", "odd", 2, 8, "odd", 4];
var oddArr = [1, 3, 5];

let currentIndex = 0;
const newArray = array.map(a => a === 'odd' ? oddArr[currentIndex++] : a)

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple and elegant solution with no side-effects.

Comment: Yes, I agree - it's a neater version of my own answer. (I hadn't figured out how to do it with just `map`, but this makes perfect sense.)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over the index, without mutating `oddArr`.

```js
const
    array = ['odd', 'odd', 2, 8, 'odd', 4],
    oddArr = [1, 3, 5],
    result = array.map((i => v => v === 'odd' ? oddArr[i++] : v)(0));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This closure is much neater than the ugly one I had added: `(i=> array.map(v => v === 'odd' ? oddArr[i++] : v))(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple loop:

```js
var array = ["odd", "odd", 2, 8, "odd", 4];
var oddArr = [1, 3, 5];

var result = [], i = 0;
array.forEach(function(x) {
  if (x === "odd") {
    result.push(oddArr[i]);
    i++;
  }
  else {
    result.push(x);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

(Note that I have replaced `odd` with the string `"odd"`, if `odd` is a real variable then you can use that instead in the above code.)

Answer (score 0):

odd should be wrapped in `''`.

```js
var array = ['odd', 'odd', 2, 8, 'odd', 4];
var oddArr = [1, 3, 5];
//lopping through array
for(let i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
    //check if item at i is odd
 if(array[i] === 'odd'){
        //oddArr.shift() returns the first element and also removes it.
  array[i] = oddArr.shift();
 }
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array with forEach() and change odd value with cross ponding one from oddArr and create index counter (x) like below

```
var array = ["odd","odd", 2, 8, "odd", 4];
var oddArr = [1, 3, 5];
var x=0;
array.forEach(function(v,i){
 if(array[i]=="odd")
 {array[i]=oddArr[x]; x++;}
 });
 console.log(array);
```