# Filter array of objects then replace

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I would like to filter, and then return the filtered array but compare with another array to see if it needs to be replaced.

For example, I want to filter `allItems` by `category_id = 2`, and then based on the `newItems` array, I want to return the filtered array but with the update item in `newItems` (if it exists).

```
allItems = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'category_id': 2,
    'text': 'old',
    'child': [
      {
        'id': 2,
        'category_id': 2,
        'text': 'old'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'category_id': 3,
    'text': 'old'
  }
]


newItems = [
  {
    'id': 2,
    'category_id': 2,
    'text': 'new'
  }
]
```

So I want to return:

```
results = [
  {
    'id': 2,
    'category_id': 2,
    'text': 'new'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'category_id': 2,
    'text': 'old'
  },
]
```

Right now, I have the filtering part but I'm not sure how to compare to another array and replace with the updated item.

```
return this.allItems.filter( (item) => {
  return item.category_id == 2
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace an item in an array with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915789/how-to-replace-an-item-in-an-array-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` followed by `.map`, to replace items (if needed) with the new item:

```js
const allItems = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'category_id': 1,
    'text': 'old'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'category_id': 2,
    'text': 'old'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'category_id': 2,
    'text': 'old'
  }
];
const newItems = [
  {
    'id': 2,
    'category_id': 2,
    'text': 'new'
  }
];

const newItemsById = newItems.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.id] = item;
  return a;
}, {});

const output = allItems
  .filter(({ category_id }) => category_id === 2)
  .map((item) => newItemsById[item.id] ? newItemsById[item.id] : item);
console.log(output);
```

Also note that your `'id': <number>` key-value pairs in your `allItems` need to be followed by commas, when followed by another key-value pair, for the syntax to be valid.

Comment: What if the item I'm trying to replace is nested in another one? I revised my example.

Comment: Just flatten the array of objects first? Use a recursive function if necessary