# How can I replace an object into an array that have a specific unique field value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am pretty new in TypeScript and rxjs and I have the following problem to solve: I have to replace a specific object into an array with another object basing on the value of an unique field.

I have done something similar to delete an object from my array having a specific value of this unique ID field:

```
this.deleteIdAction$.subscribe({
  next: (orderId) => {
    console.log("DELETE ORDER ACTION - ID: ", orderId);
    console.log("ORDERS LIST BEFORE DELETE: ", this.orders);

    this.orders = this.orders.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.id !== orderId;
    });

    console.log("NEW ORDERS LIST AFTER DELETE: ", this.orders);
  }
});
```

As you can see I used the  filter method to delete the object having a specific ID field from my array. I am not sure that this is the right choise in case I have to update a specific object.

In the specific case I have this other method that I have to use to update an object into the previous **this.orders** array.

```
this.updateOrderAction.subscribe({
  next: (orderToBeUpdated) => {
    console.log("ORDER OBJECT TO BE UPDATED: ", orderToBeUpdated);

  }
});
```

In the specific case I am receiving this **orderToBeUpdated** and I have to replace the unique object of the array having the **id** field equal to the **orderToBeUpdated.id** field value.

What could be a smart solution to implement this behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace an item in an array with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915789/how-to-replace-an-item-in-an-array-with-javascript)

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the array [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) functions.

```
this.updateOrderAction.subscribe({
  next: (orderToBeUpdated) => {
    console.log("ORDER OBJECT TO BE UPDATED: ", orderToBeUpdated);

    const indexToReplace = this.orders.findIndex(order => order.id === orderToBeUpdated.id);
    this.orders.splice(indexToReplace, 1, orderToBeUpdated);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

can you try this:

```js
const updateOrder = (o: Order): Order => { // ... update logic }

this.orders.map((o) => o.id == orderToBeUpdated ? updateOrder(o) : o )
```