# Replace all same values in array with other same values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to replace all "John"s with "Margaret"s in following code:

```
array = ["John", "John", "Herald", "John"]
```

I have tried:
`array[array.indexOf('John')] = 'Margaret'`, but that breaks.
I use React.js with TypeScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace item in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915789/how-to-replace-item-in-array)

Comment: @gorak Not quite a duplicate, though logically similar. This question wants to replace all elements of an array that meet a condition, not just the first one, and the accepted answer simply mutates the array, something we typically avoid in React.

Comment: @DrewReese look at this answer in that question https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915891/10004893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = ["John", "John", "Herald", "John"]
array.forEach((element, index) => {
   if(element === 'John') {
      array[index] = 'Margaret';
   }
 });

console.log(array); // ["Margaret", "Margaret", "Herald", "Margaret"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You would (should) need to map to a new array so you avoid array mutations.

```
["John", "John", "Herald", "John"].map(el => el === 'John' ? 'Margaret' : el);
```

```js
const array = ["John", "John", "Herald", "John"].map(el => el === 'John' ? 'Margaret' : el);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go with Drew Reese because it is a one liner and it is clean answer but if need a bit of elaboration please see below answer.

The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
const array1 = ["John", "John", "Herald", "John"];

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1.map(el => el === 'John' ? 'Margaret' : el);

console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array ["Margaret", "Margaret", "Herald", "Margaret"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceAll(arr, valueToReplace, replaceWith) {
  return arr.map(e => valueToReplace === e ? replaceWith : e)
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a prototype for better reuse and input substitution.

```
Array.prototype.replaceAll = function(find, replace){
    return this.map(function(item){
        return item === find ? replace : item;
    });
}
```

See at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHy41.png

Answer (score 0):

```js
const names = ["John", "John", "Herald", "John"]
  .join(" ")
  .replace(/John/g, "Margaret")
  .split(" ");

console.log(names);
```