# Find and replace element in array on the basis of id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
[
{
  "id":1,
  "active":1,
  "name":"paris"
},
{
  "id":2,
  "active":0,
  "name":"london"
},
{
  "id":3,
  "active":1,
  "name":"Australia"
},
{
  "id":4,
  "active":0,
  "name":"india"
}
]
```

I have a method which recieved a object as argument. object looks something like this:

```
 {
      "id":4,
      "active":0,
      "name":"india"
    }
```

In that method I want to check if element with particular id is present or not. If present I want to replace element in array with the element received in arguments. If element with that id is not found that add that element to the array. How can I do that?

Comment: how about using array [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ? to check if id matches or not

Comment: [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), if it returns `-1` add it to the array else replace the item at that index.

Comment: Buddy I am very new to JS. Could you please propose a solution? That will be very helpful

Comment: @Reyno How to replace item at that index?

Comment: Have you searched how to replace an item at an index? Cause there are more then enough [dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915789/how-to-replace-item-in-array). ([Some effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)). Hint: `array[foundIndex] = item`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
let testArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    active: 1,
    name: "paris",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    active: 0,
    name: "london",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    active: 1,
    name: "Australia",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    active: 0,
    name: "india",
  },
];

let testObj = {
  id: 4,
  active: 0,
  name: "india1",
};

let findIndex = testArr.findIndex((data) => data.id === testObj.id);
if (findIndex != -1) {
  testArr[findIndex].active = testObj.active;
  testArr[findIndex].name = testObj.name;
} else {
  testArr = [...testArr, testObj];
}
console.log("testArr=>", testArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose the following: in any case you want to have the new object included in the given array:

1. Remove Object with id from array
2. Add new Object

Could work as following:

```js
let testArr = [ ... ]
let testObj = { ... }

testArr = testArr.filter(element => element.id !== testObj.id)
testArr.push(testObj)
```

If it's necessary to keep the object in the array:

```js
let testArr = [ ... ]
let testObj = { ... }

const foundElement = testArr.find(element => element.id === testObj.id)
if (foundElement) {
  foundElement.active = testObj.active
  foundElement.name = testObj.name
} else {
  testArr.push(testObj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
const update = (data, item) => {
  const withId =  data.reduce((res, curr) => ({
    ...res,
    [curr.id]: curr
  }), {})
  withId[item.id] = item
  return Object.values(withId)
}

let testArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    active: 1,
    name: "paris",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    active: 0,
    name: "london",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    active: 1,
    name: "Australia",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    active: 0,
    name: "india",
  },
];

let testObj = {
  id: 4,
  active: 0,
  name: "india1",
};


const updated = update(testArr, testObj)

console.log(updated)
```