# To find match element in array json.file and change it [node js]

Tags: javascript, node.js

Good afternoon, I have a script that changes the value of the json file

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

async function udpateTimeInFile() {
    try {
        let data = await fsp.readFile('example.json');
        let obj = JSON.parse(data);

        obj.number = 777;

        await fsp.writeFile('example.json', JSON.stringify(obj));
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
udpateTimeInFile();
```

I need the script to find the first number 2 in the array and object **numbers** and change the unit to 3
and my json

```
{
  "foods": 111,
  "numbers": [1, 27, 5, 7, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
  "surnames": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  "date": 0
}
```

And after execution js application the file would become like this

```
{
  "foods": 111,
  "numbers": [1, 27, 5, 7, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
  "surnames": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  "date": 0
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace item in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915789/how-to-replace-item-in-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Array#findIndex` method to find the index of the first occurrence of `2`, then you can use the index to change the value to `3`.

**DEMO**

```js
const obj = {
  "foods": 111,
  "numbers": [1, 27, 5, 7, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
  "surnames": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  "date": 0
},

i = obj.numbers.findIndex(num => num === 2);

if (i > -1) {
    obj.numbers[i] = 3;
}

console.log( obj );
```

Comment: Does not work when the first element in the array is 2.