# How to map an array and delete the corresponding one

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

I have an array called responseData, it serves for me to show the available card options on the screen

```
public responseData = [
{
  id: 1399,
  pessoa_id: 75898,
  created_at: '2022-11-08T16:59:59.000000Z',
  holder: 'LEONARDO ',
  validade: '2029-05-01',
},
{
  id: 13932,
  pessoa_id: 75898,
  created_at: '2022-11-08T16:59:59.000000Z',
  holder: 'LEONARDO  L',
  validade: '2029-05-01',
},
{
  id: 139429,
  pessoa_id: 75898,
  created_at: '2022-11-08T16:59:59.000000Z',
  holder: 'LEONARDO SILVA DE L',
  validade: '2029-05-01',
},
];
```

In this case the user will click on a card, when he clicks I put the object of the card he clicked on in another variable called

```
    this.cardDelete = card;
```

So it has the option to delete this card, I would like to know a way that I could map the id of the `cardDelete` and set to null the responseData with the corresponding id

Here's an example I did on stackblitz

I put some instructions in the html

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzxnpe?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: `this.cardDelete.id` Does this not work?

Comment: @MikeS. Good idea friend, but how would I be able to delete inside the responseData?

Comment: With the `id` you can find the corresponding card in your array and then `splice` it from the array (or replace it with `null`).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915789/how-to-replace-item-in-array) may also be of help if you want to replace the card with `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you searching for is something like that:

```
    this.responseData = this.responseData.filter(
      (card) => card.id != this.cardDelete.id
    );
```

In stackblitz your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkikgw

Answer (score 0):

Using **.map** function

```
this.responseData.map((data) => {
    if (data.id == this.cardDelete.id) return null;
    return data;
});
```

look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: map should ***map*** data not filter, try using ***filter*** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @LucaAngrisani The OP did say that he'd like to replace the corresponding card with `null`. I admit this is a unique way to do it, but it does get the job done.